# Custom object not available to query in managed package application

Tags: managed-package, custom-object

We are using the managed package app and successfully installed, I can able see to all the objects under the installed package.

When I try to query from workbench/SOQL on these objects it's showing **"sObject type '`nameSpace__Obj__c`' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names"**. I am facing this problem only in Production. I went and saw the Field level security and profile all are fine.

> Issues observed: 1. Fields are showing under object as well as edit
>   Layout but not available on the detail page.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Just one query, is that user is licenced user??

Comment: @blackPerlSAF User License is Salesforce and profile is admin.

Comment: @blackPerlSAF's question was is the running user a `licensed user` of the appexchange package